# How to add record to sailsjs through association using the Blueprint REST API

Tags: sails.js

I need to implement a [through association](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations) in order to have a many-to-many relationship **with a custom field in the join table**.  In SailsJS through associations require three models; two models are your business objects, `Species` and `Lands` in my case, and a third representing the join table `SpeciesLands`.  See my SailsJS models at the bottom of this post.

Once I have the association set up how do I go about associating two objects through the blueprint API?  Do I need to `POST` data to the `/specieslands` endpoint using the id of the `Species` and `Land` I want to link?  Is it possible to create and link objects at the same time [like you can with the many-to-many](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to) relationship?  Is this something that needs to be done in a SailsJS controller rather than through the blueprint API?

Here are my models:

### Species

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        scientificName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        commonName: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        taxon: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        leadOffice: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        lands: {
            collection: 'lands',
            via: 'land',
            through: 'specieslands'
        }
    }
};
```

### Lands

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        agency: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        species: {
            collection: 'species',
            via: 'species',
            through: 'specieslands'
        }
    }
};
```

### SpeciesLands

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        species: {
            model: 'species'
        },
        land: {
            model: 'lands'
        },
        population: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            enum: ['O', 'O+', 'P', 'U'] // THIS IS THE REASON FOR ASSOCIATION
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible like that.

I am pretty sure you have to:

1. Create Specie
2. Lands
3. Relation

1 & 2 using POST /modelName
3 using http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to

Answer (score 0):

When using a `through` association, the Blueprint API will expect associations to be generated by POST into the associative model (The relation model).

In your case, if you wanted to associate an item from the Species model with an item from the Lands model, you would do something like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" 
  --request POST 
  --data '{species:15,land:51,population:"O"}' 
  http://www.example.com/SpeciesLands
```

Or in Postman:
[image: Screenshot of example API request in Postman]